# Is maintenance time considered downtime?

Tags: site-maintenance, uptime

I'm monitoring the uptime on my website. When I take the site down for a minute or so to push new code to production it shows up as a downtime event. But is it considered downtime when the site is deliberately shut down for a short period of time to push code?

It does then decrease my total uptime, which is true; in a way. The site was offline, but it was planned. Would it be more "correct" to pause the monitor and have this maintenance slots show up as un-monitored time instead?

**Update**

A 503; be right back page is shown during the maintenance.

Comment: Short answer. Yes.

Comment: If the website is "down" then it would generally be considered "downtime". Serving a maintenance page instead may not be. Setting clients' expectations is paramount.

Comment: It serves a 503; be right back page.

Comment: Downtime can be _planned_ or _unplanned_. What you are describing is _planned_ downtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closetnoc is right. Answer is yes.

Serving any page to the public with a status between 500 and 599 inclusive is an indication that something is wrong with the server.

If you are pushing code here and there, you need to download server software such as apache or nginx onto your own computer and run tests off the localhost address (127.0.0.1) and once those tests are perfect, then find the time where the users are least likely to visit your website to make updates, and when you make them, make them as fast as possible to minimize downtime.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I test everything on my staging server and pushing to production only takes about half a minute.